# adding more labels in java

Tags: java, swing, label, jframe, jlabel

Hello fellow programmers! I'm trying to add two JLabel to JFrame but the second add method that added the label seems to have overwritten my first add method. I tried solving this problem by using 2 different label variables and using setLocation method providing different coordinate point for each label. But I can't seem to solve it. Why can't I add two labels in my program? By the way, I am not getting any errors. seems to be more of a logical error I can't seem to solve.

Here's my current code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {

    private static  JLabel label;

    private static  JLabel label1;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        initializeLabel();
        initializeImage();
        initializeFrame();
    }

    private static void initializeLabel(){
         label = new JLabel();
         label.setText("hi");
         label.setLocation(54,338);
    }

    private static void initializeImage(){
        label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("sss");
        label1.setLocation(55, 340);
    }

    private static void initializeFrame(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(label1);
        frame.add(label);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}// class
```

Comment: Consider using layouts, Luke.

Answer (score 8):

Change your code following way.

```
private static void initializeFrame(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); // <-- you need this for now

    frame.add(label1);
    frame.add(label);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // optional, but nice to have.
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
}
```

Please study more on swing layout here: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

For more: [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Comment: I was trying to decide whether to up-vote either of the posts that recommended changing the layout to `FlowLayout`.  I decided your post with the code comment 'for now' and 2 links to the tutorial made the grade.  +1

Comment: @AndrewThompson: thanks for the feedback. given code sample is all written in static method. It show the asker's immaturity who is trying hard to learn java & swing. My thought was, instead of explaining all the details, I should show him how to make things right first time. As he was able to come along this far, so should will be able to pass next obstacle for sure. He just need some guidance. This is what I was thinking when I gave the answer. Thats all...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Also I have noticed his previous question on NPE, so he is good learner, I believe, who just need proper direction. He can find his solution also.

Comment: Why do peopele think their code examples are better than the Swing tutorial examples? This is not a good way to use a FlowLayout. Rarely would you ever set the content pane layout to be a FlowLayout. If you follow the tutorial example you will find that it creates a separate panel with a FlowLayout and then adds the panel to the frame, thus keeping the BorderLayout so you can add other components. Also, the example uses invokeLater(...). So let the tutorials teach people the proper coding approach (when examples exist) rather than  trying to create your own that are incomplete.

Answer (score 4):

Read up on [Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). The default layout manager for a frame is the BorderLayout. Your code is adding both labels to the CENTER of the layout. This is not possible. Each location on the BorderLayout can only contain a single component (it could be a JPanel with other components).

You need to use a different layout manager. Without knowing your exact requirement it is hard to suggest which layout manager to use.

Also, get rid of all those static methods. The Swing tutorial has plenty of example that will give you a better idea of how to structure you program.

Answer (score 3):

The default layout of [`JFrame`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) is [`BorderLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), and the default position is `BorderLayout.CENTER`.

> As a convenience, `BorderLayout` interprets the absence of a string specification the same as the constant `CENTER`.

In effect, the second label replaces the first.

Answer (score 0):

Add `frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());` after the constructing the frame.